# Applying measure zero definition to Cantor sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I just learned about the concept of measure zero in real analysis, i.e. the definition that a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has measure zero if for any $\epsilon$ it can be covered by countably many rectangles whose volume sum to $<\epsilon$.

I'm wondering if knowing only this, I can prove that the Cantor-third set has measure zero, while the fat Cantor set doesn't have measure zero.

If the answer is that I should wait until I learn more about measures in general, I will happily do that. I'm just curious whether this definition alone is enough.

Comment: Do you know about the countable additivity of measures yet? This is a *much* easier way to see the facts in question.

Comment: The middle-thirds Cantor set you can do now.  For a fat Cantor set, it is probably best to wait until you learn about Lebesge measure.

Comment: @J.Loreaux Since I only know about measure zero, I only know that a countable union of measure zero sets has measure zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is enough. If you think about the elimination process to create the Cantor set, after the first stage you see that the Cantor set can be covered by two intervals of length $1/3$ and a bit. After the second stage of middle-third removal,  you see that the Cantor set can be covered by four intervals of length $1/9$ plus a bit, etc. So after the $n^{\rm th}$ stage you see that the Cantor set can be covered in $2^n$ intervals of length $3^{-n}$ (and bit, but is is easier not to write it!). In other words, the outer measure of the Cantor set is less than $(2/3)^n$ for all $n$, and so it has to be zero.

Comment: Yes. But this only addresses the easy half of the question.

Comment: I totally missed that part ofmthe question!